# How to set attributes in suds parametrs for request?

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds

Here is a peace of request:

```
<ContinuousMove xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl">
    <ProfileToken>0</ProfileToken>
    <Velocity>
        <PanTilt x="-0.5" y="0" xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"/>
    </Velocity>
</ContinuousMove>
```

This request is called like `self._client.service.ContinuousMove(0, params)`, where `params` is like `params = {'PanTilt': [{'x': -0.5}, {'y': 0.5}]}`. The main problem is that i cant figure out how to add attributes, not values to the request. On objects it throws error that type is not found, on tuples generates this xml:

```
<ns0:ContinuousMove>
 <ns0:ProfileToken>0</ns0:ProfileToken>
 <ns0:Velocity>
    <ns1:PanTilt>x</ns1:PanTilt>
    <ns1:PanTilt>0.5</ns1:PanTilt>
    <ns1:PanTilt>y</ns1:PanTilt>
    <ns1:PanTilt>0</ns1:PanTilt>
 </ns0:Velocity>
</ns0:ContinuousMove>
```

Comment: Do you mean how to create the second parameter for `ContinuousMove`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `suds.client.Client.factory.create` to create parameter.

Here is a example I ever wrote:

```
query_param = client.factory.create("QueryCriteriaBaseOfMyTaskCriteria")

pagination_model = client.factory.create("PaginationModel")
pagination_model.PageSize = 5000
query_param.PagingInfo = pagination_model

task_criteria = client.factory.create("MyTaskCriteria")
task_criteria.LoginId = user
task_criteria.OriginatorLoginId = client.factory.create("ArrayOfInt")
task_criteria.OriginatorLoginId.int.append(int(APPLICANT))
task_criteria.ProcInstId = client.factory.create("ArrayOfInt")
if instId is not None:
    task_criteria.ProcInstId.int.append(instId)
task_criteria.ProcessCode = client.factory.create("ArrayOfString")
task_criteria.ProcessCode.string.append(PROCESSCODE)
task_criteria.Folio = ""
task_criteria.TaskStartDate = client.factory.create("DatePeriodModel")
task_criteria.ProcessStartDate = client.factory.create("DatePeriodModel")
query_param.QueryCriteria = task_criteria
ret = client.service.GetTaskList(query_param,apiKey)
```

Comment: still throwing that type not found